# SQL Stored Procedure not recieving Parameter passed from VB

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015

So I've reached a wall with my project I've been working on.  I'm trying to get a search form to function by letting the user enter data into each form field, then do a search for all specific fields.  This should return all rows that are applicable.

Whats happening is, when the user runs the search, the text is taken from the form field, and brought into VB to be validated and then pushed into a stored procedure.  The stored procedure however, is not seeing the parameters that are being passed over.  I've tried a few different methods of trying to get the data, but it's just not happening.  When I run the code with a break point, I can SEE that the text is being brought into the VB just fine, but it is not being passed as a parameter (in fact, I can't find anything in the breakpoint window that says my parameter is being generated)

The error I am receiving is:

***Procedure or function 'SearchFarmStand' expects parameter '@Farm_Business_Name', which was not supplied.***

**I have tried Googling for several hours to fix this with no success**

I've made a lot of edits in hopes that I could get it to work, but I have not been successful.  I've tried setting the default value on the parameters to NULL but that still doesn't get the parameters, although it does go through with the procedure, it just returns nothing.  On the VB side of things, I've also tried many different ways to declare the parameters using both cmd.Parameter.Add and cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue.  My code shows my most recent attempt at getting the parameter.

**Any help would be AWESOME as I'm stuck completely**

The following is my code:

**WebForm2.aspx**

```
<form id="SearchForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server">
            <div role="group" class="threecolumn-container">
                <div class="threecolumn" style="order: 1;" runat="server">
                    Farm/Business Name:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="FarmBusinessNameSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Farm/Business Owner:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="FarmOwnersSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Full Address:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="FullFarmAddressSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Address 1:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="Address1Search" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    City:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="CitySearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    State:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="StateSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
                </div>
                <div class="threecolumn" style="order: 2;"  runat="server">
                    Zip:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="ZipSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    County:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="CountySearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Phone:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="PhoneSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Website:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="WebsiteSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Email:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="EmailSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
                </div>
                <div class="threecolumn" style="order: 3;"  runat="server">
                    Dates Open:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="DatesOpenSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Dates Closed:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="DatesClosedSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Stand Open Time:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="StandOpenTimeSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Stand Closed Time:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="StandCloseTimeSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    BIO:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="BIOSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Open Ended Response:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="OpenEndedResponseSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div role="group" class="fourcolumn-container">
                <div class="fourcolumn" style="order: 1;" runat="server">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="VegetablesSearch" Text="Vegetables" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="GrainsSearch" Text="Grains" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="BreadBakedGoodsSearch" Text="Bread/Baked Goods" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="EggsSearch" Text="Eggs" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="MilksRawMilkSearch" Text="Milks/Raw Milk" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheeseSearch" Text="Cheese" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
                <div class="fourcolumn" style="order: 2;" runat="server">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CiderApplesSearch" Text="Cider/Apples" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="HoneySearch" Text="Honey" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="WineHardCiderSearch" Text="Wine/Hard Cider" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="FruitsSearch" Text="Fruits" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="BerriesSearch" Text="Berries" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="MaplesSearch" Text="Maple Goods" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
                <div class="fourcolumn" style="order: 3;" runat="server">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChickenSearch" Text="Chicken" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="TurkeySearch" Text="Turkey" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="BeefSearch" Text="Beef" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="PorkSearch" Text="Pork" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="LambSearch" Text="Lamb" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="GoatSearch" Text="Goat" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
                <div class="fourcolumn" style="order: 4;" runat="server">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="WoolFiberSearch" Text="Wool Fiber" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="WoodProductsSearch" Text="Wood Products" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="FlowersSearch" Text="Flowers" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CannedBottledGoodsSearch" Text="Canned/Bottled Goods" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="PlantSeedlingsStartsSearch" Text="Plant Seedlings/Starts" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="PlantsTreesSearch" Text="Plants/Trees" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="onecolumn">
                Other:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="OtherSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div role="group" class="twocolumn-container">
                <div class="twocolumn" style="order: 1;" runat="server">
                    Certified Organic:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="CertifiedOrganicSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Organic Certifier:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="OrganicCertifierSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Other Farms Local:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="OtherFarmsLocalSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Suplemental Catagories:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="SupplementalCatagoriesSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Being Operation:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="BeginOperationSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="PickYourOwnSearch" Text="Pick Your Own" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="EBTSearch" Text="EBT" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
                <div class="twocolumn" style="order: 2;" runat="server">
                    Staffed:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="StaffedSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Customers Peak Season:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="CustomersPeakSeasonSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Customers 2015:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="Customers2015Search" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Customers 2014:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="Customers2014Search" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    Percent Self Produced:<br /><asp:Textbox CssClass="flex-stretch" ID="PercentSelfProducedSearch" runat="server"></asp:Textbox><br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SellOtherFarmsSearch" Text="Sell Other Farms" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="LiabilityInsuranceSearch" Text="Liability Insurance" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search"/> &ensp; <asp:Button ID="ShowAllButton" runat="server" Text="Show All Farmstands"/>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Another Panel exists below for displaying my data, as well as another datalist to store the returned search data.

**Behind Code WebForm2.aspx.VB UPDATED**

```
Protected Sub SearchClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FSDATA").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.CommandText = "SearchFarmStand"
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

    'TEXTBOXES
    Dim Farm_Bussiness_Name As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Farm_Business_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
    Farm_Bussiness_Name.Value = FarmBusinessNameSearch.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Farm_Bussiness_Name)
    Dim Farm_Owners As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Farm_Owners", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
    Farm_Owners.Value = FarmOwnersSearch.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Farm_Owners)
    Dim Full_Farm_Address As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Full_Farm_Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
    Full_Farm_Address.Value = FullFarmAddressSearch.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Full_Farm_Address)
    Dim Address_1 As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Address_1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
    Address_1.Value = Address1Search.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(Address_1)
    Dim City As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
    City.Value = CitySearch.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(City)
    Dim State As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255)
    State.Value = StateSearch.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(State)
    If DatesOpenSearch.Text <> "" Then
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(DatesOpenSearch.Text)
        Dim Dates_Open As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Dates_Open", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        Dates_Open.Value = time
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Dates_Open)
    Else
        Dim Dates_Open As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Dates_Open", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        Dates_Open.Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Dates_Open)
    End If
    If DatesClosedSearch.Text <> "" Then
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(DatesClosedSearch.Text)
        Dim Dates_Closed As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Dates_Closed", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        Dates_Closed.Value = time
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Dates_Closed)
    Else
        Dim Dates_Closed As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Dates_Closed", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        Dates_Closed.Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Dates_Closed)
    End If

    ... More Textbox Dims...

    'CHECKBOXES
    If VegetablesSearch.Checked = "True" Then
        Dim Vegetables As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Vegetables", SqlDbType.Bit)
        Vegetables.Value = VegetablesSearch.Checked
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Vegetables)
    Else
        Dim Vegetables As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Vegetables", SqlDbType.Bit)
        Vegetables.Value = VegetablesSearch.Checked
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Vegetables)
    End If
    If GrainsSearch.Checked = "True" Then
        Dim Grains As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Grains", SqlDbType.Bit)
        Grains.Value = GrainsSearch.Checked
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Grains)
    Else
        Dim Grains As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(
        "@Grains", SqlDbType.Bit)
        Grains.Value = GrainsSearch.Checked
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Grains)
    End If

    ...More Checkbox Dims...

    DataList1.Visible = "False"
    DataList2.Visible = "True"
    sqlConnection1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConnection1.Close()
End Sub
```

**Stored Procedure SearchFarmStand.sql UPDATED**

```
USE [FSDATA3]
GO    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchFarmStand]
@Farm_Business_Name nvarchar(255),
@Farm_Owners nvarchar(255),
@Full_Farm_Address nvarchar(255),
@Address_1 nvarchar(255),
@City nvarchar(255),
@State nvarchar(255),
@Zip nvarchar(5),
@County nvarchar(255),
@Phone nvarchar(255),
@Website nvarchar(255),
@Email nvarchar(255),
@Dates_Open datetime = NULL,
@Dates_Closed datetime = NULL,
@Stand_Open_Time nvarchar(255),
@Stand_Close_Time nvarchar(255),
@BIO nvarchar(MAX),
@Open_Ended_Response nvarchar(255),
@Vegetables bit,
@Grains bit,
@Bread_Baked_Goods bit,
@Eggs bit,
@Milks_Raw_Milk bit,
@Cheese bit,
@Cider_Apples bit,
@Honey bit,
@Wine_Hard_Cider bit,
@Fruits bit,
@Berries bit,
@Chicken bit,
@Turkey bit,
@Beef bit,
@Pork bit,
@Lamb bit,
@Goat bit,
@Wool_Fiber bit,
@Wood_Products bit,
@Flowers bit,
@Canned_Bottled_Goods bit,
@Maples bit,
@Plant_Seedlings_Starts bit,
@Plants_Trees bit,
@Other nvarchar(255),
@Pick_Your_Own bit,
@Certified_Organic nvarchar(255),
@Organic_Certifier nvarchar(255),
@Sell_Other_Farms bit,
@Other_Farms_Local nvarchar(255),
@Supplemental_Catagories nvarchar(255),
@Begin_Operation float,
@Staffed nvarchar(255),
@Liability_Insurance bit,
@Customers_Peak_Season float,
@Customers_2015 float,
@Customers_2014 float,
@Percent_Self_Produced nvarchar(255),
@EBT bit
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ODate DATETIME
DECLARE @CDate DATETIME

SET @ODate = ISNULL(@Dates_Open, GETDATE())
SET @CDate = ISNULL(@Dates_Closed, GETDATE())

SELECT * FROM FSDATA WHERE
Farm_Business_Name LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Farm_Business_Name, Farm_Business_Name) + '%' and
Farm_Owners LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Farm_Owners, Farm_Owners) + '%' and
Full_Farm_Address LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Full_Farm_Address, Full_Farm_Address) + '%' and
Address_1 LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Address_1, Address_1) + '%' and
City LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@City, City) + '%' and
State LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@State, State) + '%' and
Zip LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Zip, Zip) + '%' and
County LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@County, County) + '%' and
Phone LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Phone, Phone) + '%' and
Website LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Website, Website) + '%' and
Email LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Email, Email) + '%' and
Dates_Open = @ODate and
Dates_Closed = @CDate and
Stand_Open_Time LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Stand_Open_Time, Stand_Open_Time) + '%' and
Stand_Close_Time LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Stand_Close_Time, Stand_Close_Time) + '%' and
BIO LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@BIO, BIO) + '%' and
Open_Ended_Response LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Open_Ended_Response, Open_Ended_Response) + '%' and
Vegetables = @Vegetables and
Grains = @Grains and
Bread_Baked_Goods = @Bread_Baked_Goods and
Eggs = @Eggs and
Milks_Raw_Milk = @Milks_Raw_Milk and
Cheese = @Cheese and
Cider_Apples = @Cider_Apples and
Honey = @Honey and
Wine_Hard_Cider = @Wine_Hard_Cider and
Fruits = @Fruits and
Berries = @Berries and
Chicken = @Chicken and
Turkey = @Turkey and
Beef = @Beef and
Pork = @Pork and
Lamb = @Lamb and
Goat = @Goat and
Wool_Fiber = @Wool_Fiber and
Cheese = @Cheese and
Wood_Products = @Wood_Products and
Flowers = @Flowers and
Canned_Bottled_Goods = @Canned_Bottled_Goods and
Maples = @Maples and
Plant_Seedlings_Starts = @Plant_Seedlings_Starts and
Plants_Trees = @Plants_Trees and
Other LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Other, Other) + '%' and
Pick_Your_Own = @Pick_Your_Own and
Certified_Organic LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Certified_Organic, Certified_Organic) + '%' and
Organic_Certifier LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Organic_Certifier, Organic_Certifier) + '%' and
Sell_Other_Farms = @Sell_Other_Farms and
Other_Farms_Local LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Other_Farms_Local, Other_Farms_Local) + '%' and
Supplemental_Catagories LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Supplemental_Catagories, Supplemental_Catagories) + '%' and
Begin_Operation = @Begin_Operation and
Staffed LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Staffed, Staffed) + '%' and
Liability_Insurance = @Liability_Insurance and
Customers_Peak_Season = @Customers_Peak_Season and
Customers_2015 = @Customers_2015 and
Customers_2014 = @Customers_2014 and
Percent_Self_Produced LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Percent_Self_Produced, Percent_Self_Produced) + '%' and
EBT = @EBT
END
```

**StackTrace**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'SearchFarmStand' expects parameter '@Farm_Business_Name', which was not supplied.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2434922
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5736592
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +379
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2026
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +375
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +139
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +136
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +86
System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1494
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.GetData() +58
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +294
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +64
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind() +81
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.EnsureDataBound() +62
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.CreateChildControls() +69
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

Comment: I don't see in the ASPX code any reference to the SearchClick method. Did you forget to add the "OnClick=SearchClick" part? Also in the SearchClick method I see a lot of unnecessary code but not a call to the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Where do you execute your `SqlCommand` (i.e. `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`)? I see you open the connection then immediately close it.

Comment: @Steve If you mean: 
<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search"/>

Then no I have not included the OnClick=SearchClick as it runs the VB just fine. When I run the debugger and throw in a breakpoint where it grabs the text out of the FarmBussinesNameSearch field in the SearchClick event, it still fires and grabs the text.  My issue seem to be in the parameter being seen by the stored procedure.

Just tested it to be sure, and yup, even with the OnClick event, it's the same outcome.

Comment: @zgood
Wow I didn't even notice that, let me go ahead and test this, I'll get back to you

Comment: Ah got it...... "@Farm_Bussines_Name",  notice the two s in "Bussines", the stored procedure doesn't like your spelling;-)..... It is just a typo, you could delete the question

Comment: I think @Steve has figured it out.

Comment: Having some datetime conversion issues, I will report back if all is well afterwords.

I have an inkling it has to primarily do with the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() not being in the event, as I have ran some tests that ignored the Farm_Business_Name dim and param.

Comment: Okay, so I've gone ahead and updated everything and dealt with the conversions, however, after changing the Procedure to reflect the right spelling and adding the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), I am still recieving the "Procedure or function 'SearchFarmStand' expects parameter '@Farm_Business_Name', which was not supplied." error.

I will update my post to include my new code

Comment: I'm out of the office til Monday, so if I don't get some kind of resolution before then, I'll have to repost the question since I'm being downvoted for some reason (The question hasn't been answered as of this comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was happening.  I had an extra SQLDataSource that was set to pull the stored procedure, however there were no parameters being set within the sqldatasource.  This was separate from the VB that I had created to create the parameters.  What I've done is removed the needless sqldatasource and my code is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="VegetablesSearch" Text="Vegetables" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox><br />

If VegetablesSearch.Text = "True"
```

What makes you think the text of the CheckBox will be "True"?

Comment: This is one of my first VB projects, so I'm learning as I go.  I've updated my code after trying the fixes suggested in the main post to better reflect how it should see the checkbox.  This however is not answering my question listed above. Thanks

Comment: Are you still getting the parameter missing error?  Did you set a breakpoint and step through your code to make sure that the parameters are being built and added as you expect?

Comment: Hey there, so ive used the breakpoint before and checked to see if the value is being set, but i cannot find the @Farm_Business_Name id under the parameter list.  Is there a specifc place i can look to see the param?

Comment: You need to breakpoint before the code where @Farm_Business_Name parameter is built, then keep hitting F10 to see if the parameter is actually being built and added with the value you expect.

Comment: Hey there.  So I did the breakpoint again and I can see that Farm_Business_Name is being set and is of the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter type.  When I drill down into the name, I can see the Param name is set to "@Farm_Business_Name" and has an sql value of whatever I type into the textbox.  However, I am still getting the error.